# Validating Query Params in REST API

Tags: java, rest, api-design, vert.x

I have a REST API which accepts query parameters. `The query parameters are valid if and only if at a time only one query parameter is passed and it is among the list of valid query parameters.`

Currently my logic for this is:

I am collecting the query params in a map. And then checking it's size. If size > 1 function throwing an error. If that is not the case then iterating through the map and if  find a parameter other than valid ones the function throwing an error.

For example:

```
if(queryParam.size()>1) {
        throw new FailureResponse();
    }

queryParam.forEach(e->{
        String key = e.getKey();
        if(!key.equalsIgnoreCase("p1") && !key.equalsIgnoreCase("p2")) {
            throw new FailureResponse();
        }

    });
```

But I think in this way I am violating the SOLID design principle which says `a class should be open for extension but closed for modification.`

I also thought of `creating a file and then reading the acceptable params` from it but that would add to the response time of the API as it involves reading a file.

**Is there some way I can keep and read the valid query-params and it does not violate the design principles?**

Comment: In a perfect REST scenario you would provide a client with any possible links it might use and clients would use the provided links to progress their task. However, almost any REST API out there is actually closer to RPC than to REST which bear the danger of shifting responsibilities and knowledge from one point to the other. I'm also not sure if returning errors is that benefitial. IMO ignoring unwanted ones would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain an Enum of valid params and extend the enums as and when applicable like

```
public enum QueryParams{
      PARAM_1("param1"),
      PARAM_2("param2"),

      private String paramValue;
      QueryParams(String paramName){
        this.paramValue = paramValue();
      }
      public void getParamValue(){
         return this.value;
      }
}
```

and then you could iterate over the set of values of this enum to filter out invalid values

```
List<String> validParams = Arrays.asList(QueryParams.values()).stream().map(QueryParams::getParamValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
    queryParams.removeAll(validParams);
    if(queryParams.size()!=0) {
        throw new FailureResponse();
    }
}
```

This helps you maintain the API class without any changes, whenever a new parameter is added, just extend the enum and all the rest is automatically extended as it all depends upon the value in the enum.

Comment: "extend the enums as and when applicable". Could you give some example as extending/implemeting enums is not possible in Java.

Comment: @YugSingh you are right, enums cannot be extended. What i meant was add new values to this enums.